# PostGIS 3D linestring validity with two different Z coordinates

Tags: postgis

Maybe I missed something in the docs, but why is this not a valid `LINESTRING Z` and is a `POINT Z` when calling `st_makeValid`?

```
select st_isvalid(st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING Z (0 0 0,0 0 10)'));

st_isvalid
---------------
f


select st_astext(st_makevalid(st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING Z (0 0 0,0 0 10)')));
st_astext
---------------
POINT Z (0 0 0)
```

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. `SELECT st_isvalid('LINESTRING Z(0 1 1, 0 0 10)'::geometry);` returns true, while `SELECT st_isvalid('LINESTRING Z(0 0 1, 0 0 10)'::geometry);` returns false.

Comment: Interestingly, if you call something like ST_Expand on the invalid Linestring Z, it works as expected. `SELECT ST_Astext(ST_Expand('LINESTRING Z(0 0 0, 0 0 10)'::geometry, 1, 1, 1));` returns  POLYGON Z ((-1 -1 -1,-1 1 -1,1 1 11,1 -1 11,-1 -1 -1)). I will have a look at the source code later to see if I can find the bug, but, it looks to me that you can probably ignore the ST_Isvalid error. Also, note that ST_GeomFromText is not necessary to construct a LINESTRING Z.

Comment: I asked on the Postgis dev IRC channel and ST_IsValid only works in 2D, which explains why 0 0 0, 0 0 10 fails and 0 1 0, 0 0 10 works. sfcgal, on which the 3D extensions are based does have an IsValid function. I have been told to request an ST_3dIsValid function be hooked up to sfcgal and the docs be updated. As I suggested before, you are safe to carry on using LINESTRING Z. I will update this once I have filed the bug/request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour as the existing Postgis/GEOS codebase only checks 2D coordinates, ie, it ignores the z coordinate.

If you run,

```
SELECT ST_IsValid('LINESTRING Z(0 1 0, 0 0 10)'::geometry);
```

it returns **true**, as you now have a valid 2D LINESTRING.

I was advised on the Postgis developers irc channel to file a [feature request](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4363), to request a **ST_3dIsValid** function that would hook into the existing [sfcgal IsValid function](https://github.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/blob/master/src/algorithm/isValid.cpp) and, also, a request to  update the docs for ST_IsValid.

Note, for now, you can ignore ST_IsValid with LINESTRING Z, as the underlying functionality appears to be correct, eg,

```
SELECT ST_Astext(ST_Expand('LINESTRING Z(0 0 0, 0 0 10)'::geometry, 1, 1, 1));
```

returns:

> POLYGON Z ((-1 -1 -1,-1 1 -1,1 1 11,1 -1 11,-1 -1 -1))

Comment: What I found out recently is that in some cases it does not work correctly. For example, intersections are not returning correct results:
`select st_intersects(st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING Z(5 5 1000,5 5 2000)'), st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(0 0, 10 10)'));` returns `false` while making the 3D geometry valid from the 2D point of view fixes the call. This is actually really annoying and hard to debug since it returns correct result sometimes when in the middle of the large query (for some reason).

Comment: @Novotmike. That sounds annoying. I found an error in sfcgal before and the dev fixed it the same day. I put in a bug report, spoke to him on the postgis dev channel, sorted same day. To be fair it was a memory leak and a one line fix, but, if you are able to put together some kind of minimal cases showing your problems, I am sure it'll get fixed.